# Modifying Keyboard Layout in Wayland

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

My laptop came with a PrintScreen key (on the right hand side of KB between to the Alt_R and Control_R). In Xorg, I've been using xmodmap to swap the printscreen with a menu key:

/usr/bin/xmodmap -e "keycode 107 = Menu"

Problem is that xmodmap, xdotool and anything else that relies on intercepting and injecting keystrokes doesn't work anymore on Wayland due to security restrictions. gnome-tweak-tool had (out of the box) a few nifty xkb based  modifications that allowed swapping out some specific keys (like capslock with escape) but it didn't have the modification I was looking for.

I was wondering if there was a way of swapping the printscr for a menu key by modifying the keyboard layout files? Are they text files or are they binary files that I'd have to re-compile?

There's setkeycodes and getkeycodes in /usr/bin, does anyone know what these commands do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to modify XKB files. I'd guess that the bottom of the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin` file may give you a hint for your case - unless the XKB option `altwin:prtsc_rwin` does what you want.

**Additional Info**

In terminal, enter:

```
sudo su
nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin
```

At the bottom of the file you will find:

```
// Win is mapped to the PrtSc key (and the usual Win key).
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "prtsc_rwin" {
    replace key <PRSC> { [ Super_R, Super_R ] };
    modifier_map Mod4 { <PRSC>, <RWIN> };
};
```

Delete this section and replace it with this:

```
// Menu is mapped to the PrtSc key (and the usual Win key).
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "prtsc_rwin" {
     replace key <PRSC> { [ Menu, Menu ] };
     modifier_map Mod4 { <PRSC>, <MENU> };
};
```

To delete in nano, use backspace key (highlighting and deleting doesn't work). To paste, use shift-ctrl-v. To exit and save, press ctrl-x, select yes to overwrite and press enter.

Reboot.
In Gnome/Ubuntu
Go to gnome-tweak-tools
In tweak tools go to Keyboard & Mouse section, press the Additional Layout Options button and expand Alt/Win key behavior. Selecting the option on the very bottom: Win is mapped to printscr (remember that we've modified just this behavior to swap print and Menu instead of print and Win).
(I'm sure there is a way of turning on the modded xkb option in KDE but I don't use it, so I can't give you the exact procedure).

Comment: @thebunnyrules be aware this edit is to a system file, and will be overwritten by updates of the `xkb-data` package.  keep a backup handy!

Comment: @quixotic: Thanks for mentioning that. Because many users edit files belonging to `xkb-data`, we avoid to update that package in stable releases. But in connection with upgrades to a newer Ubuntu release you need to redo it more often than not.